# Confusion about time complexity with hash maps

Tags: c++, time-complexity

On leetcode I find it is common to "ignore" the worst-case time complexity involving hash maps. I thought in software interviews that it was standard to assume "worst case" as they often do. Below is my solution to a simple problem. The problem is to find the first non repeating char in a string. I understand that hash maps are on average O(1) lookup.. but when iterating over the string, and looking up the hash map, why is the time complexity not O(N^2) and instead is O(N)?

```
#include <unordered_map>

class Solution {
public:
    unordered_map<char, int> m;
    
    int firstUniqChar(string s) {
        for(char c : s) {
            m[c]++;
        }
        for(int i =0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if(m[s[i]] == 1) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        
        return -1;
    
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is on average `O(N)` because hash map is on average `O(1)` per lookup and you do `O(N)` of them.

*On average* means by averaging over all possible inputs. That means there might exists an input array that breaks a particular hash and achieves `O(N)` or much worse on every lookup.

Worst-case is heavily implementation specific - e.g. hashing into buckets depends on how are elements stored in each bucket. If they are in a simple list, then lookup is `O(<duplicates>)`, binary tree will bring that down to `O(log<duplicates>)`. There might also be a difference between searching for keys present and missing.

Also there is a big assumption that all hashed containers can grow with the number of elements stored. I.e. keeping the occupancy of buckets low.

It does not hurt to mention their worst-cases in interviews, it demonstrates you know they can have limits.

Comment: Are you saying that really in interviews and in general the average case is what it stated, rather than the worst case? I understand why the average complexity is O(N).

Comment: @JSman More like, that it is good to be able to distinguish between them. Take quicksort, everyone will say it runs in `O(nlogn)` because it usually does. But its worst-case is `O(n^2)` unless you get fancy with picking the pivot. And if you do, you will get guaranteed optimal `O(nlogn)` yet it is not used in practice because it is slower. The real performance is always more important than any asymptotical complexity and sometimes the average complexity is a better measure of that. Do not focus on interview questions, focus on understanding, then you won't care what they ask you.

Answer (score 2):

The time-complexity of the given problem is O(N). You may provide a [perfect hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) for it, that is no collision ever happens. This perfect hash function here is `static_cast<size_t>(256+c)`. Well, if you look at the fastest solutions to this problem on leetcode you see that guys use plain arrays.

---

Comment: It makes sense that an array is used given there's only 26 spots required.